# BizTalk Server 2016 Can you retrieve terminated messages?

Tags: biztalk, terminate

Some resumable messages were terminated today by mistake. Is there a way to retrieve them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, if the messages were being Tracked for some reason.

You should still see the Terminated Instances on the Terminated list in the Group Hub.  *If* the messages were set for Tracking, you would be able to retrieve them there.

If not, your only option would be to restore the databases to a point before Terminate was issued.